# Options for paging and sorting a DynamoDB result set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm starting on a new project and am going to be using DynamoDB as the main data source. A lot of what it does works perfectly for the needs, with a couple exceptions.

Those are the sorting and paginating needs of the UI. Users can sort the data by anywhere from 8-10 different columns, and a result set of 20-30k+ rows should be paginated over.

From what I can tell of DynamoDB, the only way to do sorting by all those columns would be to expose that many sort keys through a variety of additional indexes, and that seems like a misuse of those concepts. If I'm not going to sort the data with DynamoDb queries, I can't paginate there either.

So my question is, what's the quickest way once I have the data to paginate & sort? Should I move the result set into Aurora and then sort & page with SQL? I've thought about exporting to S3 and then utilizing something like Athena to page & sort, but that tool really seems to be geared to much larger datasets than this. What are other options?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to duplicate the data and store it once for each sorting option, with each version of the record having different data in the sort key. If you are okay with eventual consistency that might be a little more delayed you can accomplish this by having a lambda that reads from a DynamoDB stream and insert/update/delete the sorted records as the main records are inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: I actually like that idea. Is there a reason to go with a stream and lambda's writing it back in rather than just doing the initial inserts/updates/deletes multiple times with the different sort key values? From my limited understanding so far it doesn't seem like it's much of a resource burden to just do more writes initially.

Comment: It can make it easier to manage the code that is just managing the main records, and removes the need to deal with transactions (which are limited). In simple cases you can just do it all at the same time, but I prefer a more robust solution.

Comment: The stream-based approach would mean that you do not have to replicate the logic of creating duplicates wherever you have client code that modifies the golden data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting, pagination and returning 20-30K records are not Dynamo's strong suit...

Why not just store the data in Aurora in the first place?

Depending on the data, Elasticsearch may be a better choice.  Might even look at Redshift.

**EDIT**
If you've not seen this before...
[image: PIE Theorem]

Comment: Consistent write/update performance right now is the main appeal of DynamoDb, but I definitely have considered Aurora as well. Hooking DynamoDb streams to push data into an Elasticsearch makes a lot of sense. I'll look into that as well.

Comment: You don't mention the data, but if RDS compatible, and you've watched a deep dive into Aurora, I highly recommend doing so.  It's impressive.